# How to configure Fedora/Ubuntu desktop with a bash script?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, automation, desktop, configure

The default appearance of Fedora desktop is not what I desire. So I will always change some settings through GUI-based "System Settings" after a new installation.

However, I feel it is rather tedious to click, click, and click again. I think it must have a way to write a bash script to automate this dirty work.

Where are the config files storing those setting?

How to find the documentation indicating the locations of the related config files?

Answer (score 0):

kwriteconfig: http://archive.news.softpedia.com/news/Hidden-KDE-Options-and-Features-53213.shtml

Do not forget to re-read your config using:

```
qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin reconfigure
```